# SAP HANA: Loading tables from with statements in stored procedures

Tags: sql, hana

Is it possible to load a table from a with statement via a stored procedure in HANA? Nothing i try seems to work, and the only thing that does work when creating a procedure is just displaying the data from the with statement via a select. Below I show three examples I have tried for accessing with statement data. Currently on HANA revision 84. Please note the table create is just for purposes of the test example.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
AS

BEGIN

create table t1 (cal_day date);

with w1 as (
    select current_date cal_day from dummy
    )

--works just fine but isn't loading the data into anything
select * from w1;

--get indentifier must be declared error
select cal_day into t1 from w1;

--get incorrect syntax error    
insert into t1
    select cay_day from w1;

END
```

Comment: You normally would not create any permanent (non-temporary) tables in a sql stored procedure. Stored procs are for data access, not data definition.

Comment: Sorry, yes the table create was for the purpose of the test case example. In my real life scenario the table being loaded to is already created.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to execute DDL statements in a SQLScript procedure you'll need to use dynamic SQL for that (EXEC).

Comment: do you have an example of how to accomplish the same thing with dynamic SQL?

Comment: Sorry, but looking at your code and your comments it looks as if you didn't check the syntax reference.

Of course you cannot access a table in a static context (INSERT INTO T1) that is not there when you compile the procedure.